# Capture frame from 10-bit video using Python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I want to capture a frame from 10-bit video. I tried some solutions to that, like OpenCV but it seems to cause strong banding in dark areas on saved image, and FFMPEG but quality is inferior to OpenCV and it seems to handle YUV colorspace incorrectly when saving the image (black areas lose much detail, and picture is overall brighter).

I'm disregarding frame accuracy at this point, what i care most about is proper handling of colors.

I wanted to try VapourSynth, but i can't get it to work properly on my Ubuntu (compilation fails when enabling imwrt plugin).

What other solutions i can try for that problem?

One thing i can think of is dithering dark areas with OpenCV to get rid of banding, but i honestly don't know how to do that, and when i tried some already-made alghoritms(like [this one](https://github.com/bharathkotari/image-Dithering-using-Opencv-python/blob/master/source/image_dethering.py) ) but it didn't work at all, getting stuck at one of set_pixel functions.

EDIT: diffrence between ffmpeg, OpenCV, and mpv 8 bit screenshots: 
https://diff.pics/zugzxgSvGI3D

Looks like OpenCV has trouble converting 10 bit to 8 bit image, causing strong debanding, but there is much more details in dark areas. 8 bit screenshot taken with MPV looks probably best, and that's what i'm aiming for. Only thing wrong with OpenCV one in that case would be strong banding.

Comment: Can you provide a pointer to a 10-bit video file that we can use to demonstrate a solution to your problem?

Comment: I'll post one when i get home along with frames captured using ffmpeg and OpenCV as comparison as well.

Comment: Very good, in the meantime, try to resist the urge to patch the symptom rather than find and address the problem at its source.

Comment: I've updated question with diff link.

Comment: I'm sorry, we need an actual input file with the 10 bit data.   Also, it would be best if you could provide an example of what your are trying to do in a minimum number of lines of code.

Comment: I actually solved it using VapourSynth. Quality is very good, it provides in-built dithering and is much faster than using OpenCV when it comes to opening whole file.

Comment: That's fine, but since you posted the question, it would be nice to post in a form that we can respond to and post an answer.  Handling 10 bit image data could be useful information for  someone.